# Query dentro de combobox multiselect

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery

Tengo este combo pero los  son un query, y quiero implementar el mutiselect y pero como no son datos fijos son querys como implementaria el mutiselect? ya tengo un jQuery que me deja "seleccionar todos" pero no me trae los campos del select del query

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
                $("#product02").multipleSelect();
                $("#product02").val(<?php echo $product02 ?>);
                $("#product02").multipleSelect('refresh');
            });


<div class="col-md-2">
    <?
    $query="SELECT restId, id, name FROM products WHERE restId in($restaurantIdsAux) and active=1 ORDER BY restId,name";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $prodsArr[$row['restId']][$row['id']]=$row['name'];
    }

    $product = (int) $_POST['product'];
    ?>

    <label>Producto:</label>
    <select name="product" id="product">

        <?
        foreach($prodsArr as $sucId => $prods){
            echo '<option value="" id="'.$sucId.'"'; if($_POST['product']=='') echo ' selected'; echo '>Todos</option>';
            foreach($prods as $code => $prod){
                echo '<option id="'.$sucId.'M'.$code.'" value="'.$code.'"'; 
                if($_POST['product']==$code and $restId==$sucId) echo 'selected'; echo '>'.$prod.'</option>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    </div>
```

A resumir, quiero implementar el multiselect en un combobox que las opciones las trae de un query consulta mysql

Comment: primero que nada el query o consulta es independiente de la funcionalidad de tu select, una vez armado tu consulta y agregado las opciones mediante tu id creas o aplicas el multiselect

Comment: verifica que tu id sea el correcto en el codigo apuntas a "product02" pero en el html tienes.."product"..